# What are the books referenced in the C FAQ?

Tags: c

What are the books referenced in the C FAQ e.g. the ones at the bottom of
this page http://c-faq.com/expr/evalorder2.html

```
K&R1
K&R2
ISO
H&S
CT&P
PCS
```

I know K&R refers to "The C Programming Language" by "Kernighan and Ritchie". Can someone clarify the rest.

Comment: Herb Schildts' books are definitely ones of the best. They contain nice and easy to follow examples.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/sx2/index.html

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Apparently some people have a different opinion about his books see section "stuff that should be avoided" in http://www.iso-9899.info/wiki/Books Maybe this changed.

Comment: "his knowledge of C is limited and inaccurate", I think that claim is outright offensive. Sad to read such things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- ANSI - American National Standards Institute, American National Standard for Information Systems--Programming Language--C
- CT&P Andrew Koenig, C Traps and Pitfalls
- H&S Harbison and Steele, C: A Reference Manual
- ISO - International Organization for Standardization, ISO 9899:1990
- Knuth - Donald Knuth, The Art of Computer Programming
- PCS - Mark Horton, Portable C Software
- Rationale - American National Standards Institute, Rationale for American National Standard for Information Systems--Programming Language--C